# Boundary function of product of $H^\infty$ and $H^2$ function

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

If $f\in H^2$ and $\phi \in H^\infty$ is it true that $\widetilde{\phi f} = \tilde{\phi}\tilde{f}$?
It is is easy to see that
$
\widetilde{z^nf} = \tilde{z^n}\tilde{f} 
$
and so for all polynomials $p$ it is true 
$
\widetilde{pf} = \tilde{p}\tilde{f} $ How can this be carried forward to $H^\infty$ functions if at all?

Comment: General suggestion: add a broad area tag along with a specific tag like [tag:hardy-spaces]. A tag with 42 questions in it probably doesn't get much traffic.

Comment: yes, will take care. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boundary function $\tilde f$ of an $H^p$ function $f$ is (almost everywhere) just the ordinary   limit of $f$ in radial direction (normal to the boundary, for general smooth domains). Since the limit of a product is the product of limits, the claim follows.

(Remark: the product of an $H^p$ function and an $H^\infty$ function is in $H^p$, since multiplication by a bounded function contributes at most a constant factor to the integrals hat determine the $H^p$ norm.)

Comment: thanks! will writing the cauchy product series $\widetilde{\phi f}$ and $\tilde{\phi}\tilde{f}$ and comparing the coefficient be a correct argument ?

Comment: I don't know, I'd have to see the argument first. How it uses the assumption $\phi\in H^\infty$ through the coefficients... etc.

Comment: when you say that limit of product is product of limit, it is fine, but it does not say that this product is in $\tilde{H^2}$. But as $\phi$ is in $H^{\infty}$ product of $\phi$ and $f$ is in $H^2$ and so it's boundary fnctn is in $\tilde{H^2}$ and it is okay to write $\tilde{\phi}\tilde{f}$ as $\widetilde{\phi f}$.This can be proved by growth condition.so this supporting argument is needed to your answer as well.i was asking that can we say $T(\sum b_n z^n \sum a_n z^n) =? T (\sum b_n z^n)T(\sum a_n z^n)$ by cmparing coefficients of $z^n$ in cauchy product on each side?$(T(f)=\tilde{f})$